# ORA-00936: missing expression while using stringbuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stringbuilder

I am using `StringBuilder` to use multiple queries in `asp.net`. But I am getting error as

> ORA-00936: missing expression

Below is my query.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue != "0")
{
    sb.Append("insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h  select sysdate,* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
    sb.Append(";");
    sb.Append("update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'");
    sb.Append(";");
}
if (ddlProject.SelectedValue != "0" && ddlBuilding.SelectedValue == "0")
{
    sb.Append("insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h  select sysdate,* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");
    sb.Append(";");
    sb.Append("update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'");
    sb.Append(";");
}

OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
OracleCommand cmd1 = new OracleCommand();
string allQueries = sb.ToString();
cmd1.CommandText = allQueries;
cmd1.Connection = ObjPriCon;
ObjPriCon.Open();
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here is the error caused
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Record updated successfully');window.location ='FrmHoldingCoordinateUpdate.aspx?TranType=FM&PView=N&Mode=A&Redirect=oracle&Key=0&Redirect=" + Request.QueryString["Redirect"] + "&userid=" + Request.QueryString["userid"].ToString() + "';", true);
```

Also, `allQueries` gives result as

`insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h  select getdate(),* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL;update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '5681';`

Comment: Does Oracle support 'GETDATE()'?

Comment: @ThomasSchremser: Nope, sorry my mistake, I will change it. Is that the error ?

Comment: shouldnt there be  semi-colon after insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h

Comment: @Mysterio11: can you give the syntax which you telling ?

Comment: my bad i was wrong. but what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Mysterio11: First, I want to update the history table with the data from main table. Then Insert into the main table with fresh data in **ORACLE**

Comment: the way to find current date in oracle is SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "NOW"
     FROM DUAL;

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need use alias for table name before `*`
For example:

```
insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h  select getdate(),t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t;
```

Comment: And, to clarify this (correct) answer: select * from... works, but it doesn't work if you add other columns, such as `sysdate`. In such cases you must use the table name (or alias) before *.

Comment: @mathguy: I used it like this `insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h select sysdate,t.* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL t` but getting error as **ORA-00911: invalid character**

Comment: @mathguy: the answer posted by `Surename` is not working for me

Comment: @nad:  Can you separate insert and update, and execute them as two different query?  I think problem in `;` You can try remove `update` query, just for test.

Comment: @nad - that is wrong, and unfair to Surename. Clearly his answer DID work, since it cleared your "missing expression" error. Now you have a different error - this means your code has many problems, not one. That is not Surename's fault. Blaming volunteers who give you correct answers for your other mistakes in your code won't win you many friends on this or any other site.

Comment: @Surename: I tried your single statement too, it gives error as `ORA-00947: not enough values`

Comment: @mathguy: even his answer is not working, I still get the error as `ORA-00947: not enough values`

Comment: @mathguy: actually, while inserting into the history table, there is a `SEQ` column whose name is `HISTSEQ_NO` and it is also unique. So how to insert values in this ?

Comment: @nad It is another error. 
Please, check count of columns in source and destination tables. I think destination table `xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h` has more columns, than you try insert.

Comment: @nad Return to error `ORA-00911: invalid character` You can try another way. Place you expressions in anonymous block. For example:

    `sb.Append("BEGIN  ");`
    `sb.Append("insert into xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL_h  select sysdate,* from xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL");`
    `sb.Append("; ");`
    `sb.Append("update xxacl_pN_LEASES_ALL set ASSIGNED_TO = '" + ddlSalesUser.SelectedValue + "'");`
    `sb.Append(";");`
    `sb.Append("  END;");`
 

I haven't got  C# environment, but I think this exaple must work.